# Grand potential physical meaning

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Take the classical Grand canonical ensemble.
Its grand potential $J$ could be defined as:

$$J=\langle U \rangle-T\langle S \rangle-\mu\langle N\rangle = \langle F\rangle-\mu\langle N\rangle$$

$F$, the Helmholtz free energy, has an intuitive significance: the energy "available to do work", "purified" from entropy.

But what about J? Could I think of it as the "available energy", "purified" from entropy *and* from the energy stored in the $N$ molecules (if $\mu >0$)?